How run flutter app in Android emulator as default in VS code
After upgrade my flutter to new version, after click on Run > Run Without Debugging
get in terminal
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:50654/jXOXgpSaXOX=/ws
How open app in emulator?
I have emulator Android Pixel 6....
Note:  web folder is deleted from project
Android emulator is available, before few days all is working fine.
Any solution how set Android Emulator as default?

In the bottom status bar, there is a section that displays the currently selected device. If you click on that, you can change the default device:

Likewise, if you have the Flutter plugin, there is a tab on the sidebar with the Flutter logo. That also lets you see the available devices:

Finally, you can make sure the emulator is running by using the Flutter: Launch Emulator command in the command palette.

